# Bootstrap! Is there a such thing as hidden-sm

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Working in Bootstrap and I have a row with two columns - image in one column, text in the other. All I want to do is hide the image on col-sm and col-xs devices. Is there a way to do this? All I've found is hidden-xs.

HTML

```
<section id="financialPlanning">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-m-12 col-lg-3 pull-left hidden-xs">
    <p><p>         
    <img src="images/compass-img.png" alt="Retirment" class="img-responsive"> 
    </div>


<div class="col-sm-8 col-m-10 col-lg-9">
<font size="5">FINANCIAL PLANNING</font>
<p>Financial planning is never a one-dimensional process. It entails coordinating numerous factors that touch 
upon your investments, future income requirements, estate plan, tax situation and other key 
considerations.</p>
<p>A strong financial plan gives you an objective view of your overall financial picture and provides you with 
the guidance you need to enjoy a stress free retirement. Our Relationship Managers have the 
experience, expertise, and resources to help you and your family create and implement a thoughtful 
and disciplined financial plan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use .hidden-sm and .hidden-xs class to hide content for both tablet and mobile

Comment: @YogeshSharma, Thanks for the feedback. That worked. I'm a tad embarrassed that the solution was that easy. #NewToBootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to hide image on tablet and mobile devices.

To hide image on both devices you can use ".hidden-sm" (to hide in tablet) and ".hidden-xs" (to hide in mobile) classes.

Please see this http://getbootstrap.com/css/ post; in the "Grid options" section you can find browser related classes and in "Available classes" section you can see classes to hide content in different-2 devices.